# Transferring real time network logs from one Ec2 instance to another Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

Explanation:

- I have one executable Jar deployed on one EC2 instance which can be run manually to listen on port 80 for proxy traffic
- I have one Spring application on another EC2 instance which hits a website on third party server

Connection between these two machines:

Spring application setup i.e. B tells third party server to open a website and use A as a proxy, this leads to generation of logs of network calls on A.

What I want to do is: for every request I send from B to third party server I want network logs that are being generated on A to be transferred to B

What I tried:

1. One way is to rotate logs on A and write to S3 and then application and pick it from S3 and process them
2. ssh into A and grep the log file, but this stops the JAR to listen to the new traffic and it gets stuck

What I am looking for:

A realtime solution, as soon as logs show up on A I want them to be ported to B without stopping A on its listening job

Comment: 'Real time' has a specific meaning in IT, and this isn't it. Please don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what OS you are running, but if you are running a nix variant, you can install syslog-ng instead of syslog, or rsyslog, which is capable of logging local and external events. In this case I would set up a central logging server, that listens for logs from server a, and server b.

Another alternative is syslog-ng is not what you're looking for, you could install splunk on a server, and have it pick up the logs from splunk reporters on each server you want to centrally log.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin mentioned , you could set up a Splunk Indexer on an EC2 instance and use this to aggregate the collection of logs from A and B and any other sources , and then use the Splunk Search language to search over this log data in "near realtime", correlate events together across your various systems , create custom dashboards, setup proactive alerting etc...

http://www.splunk.com/

As far as the mechanisms for getting this data from your systems to the Splunk Indexer :

1) Use a Splunk Universal Forwarder to monitor log output and forward it to your Splunk Indexer , http://www.splunk.com/download/universalforwarder

2) As your systems are Java based , SplunkJavaLogging has log4j/logback/jdk appenders that you can seamlessly wire in to your logging config to forward log events to your Splunk Indexer : https://github.com/damiendallimore/SplunkJavaLogging

3) Use the Splunk Java SDK , http://dev.splunk.com/view/java-sdk/SP-CAAAECN , to input log events into your Splunk Indexer via HTTP REST or Raw TCP